# http to https in TOMCAT

Tags: ssl, tomcat, java-8, server.xml

I am able to convert http to https by adding below entry in server.xml of the tomcat. My truststore is having password and I don't want to leave like this.

```
<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
               acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="/Users/myapp/tomcat/conf/apptruststore.jks" keystorePassword="myP@ssw0rd"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

My  question is any other way to implement this ? like keeping it in a server side java code or adding encryption in server.xml.

Comment: If you encrypt the password, you need to encrypt the key used to encrypt the password and the key used to encrypt the key... and [it's turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down).

Comment: So what is the best way to deal with this ?

Comment: Configure the file system permissions of both `server.xml` and `apptruststore.jks` properly: only Tomcat and the administrator should be able to read it. Don't use a valuable password (i.e. a password you use elsewhere and remember), generate it randomly.

Comment: is it possible to handle it through my application ? using SSLContext or javax.naming.Context?